# Scalafmt: keep empty lines in a List

Tags: scala, scala-3, scalafmt

I want to keep a single empty line in the List definition using the scalafmt formatter:

```scala
List(
  "some-random-string1"
    .trim
    .stripMargin,

  "some-random-string2"
    .intern
    .dropRight(3),

  "some-random-string3"
    .takeRight(4)
    .substring(10)
)
```

The formatter removes the empty lines and breaks the readability of such code.
My `.scalafmt.conf` configuration:

```
version = "3.7.3"
runner.dialect = scala3
align.preset = most
newlines.source = keep
```

I want to find a way to configure the formatter to keep the empty lines.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a one-time occurrence in your code, you might want to use `// format: off` and `// format: on` around the relevant code to ask `scalafmt` to preserve its current formatting ([documentation](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#-format-off)):

```
// format: off
List(
  "some-random-string1"
    .trim
    .stripMargin,

  "some-random-string2"
    .intern
    .dropRight(3),

  "some-random-string3"
    .takeRight(4)
    .substring(10)
)
// format: on
```

Comment: Well, it's an option for a one-time occurrence, but I need a configurable solution.

Comment: What would you like to happen? Preserve all the line breaks? Insert line breaks in non-well-formatted code? In which contexts?

Comment: The format off option completely disables the formatting of the code, but I want to have formatting enabled with keeping the line breaks inside a List

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is an option specifically to only keep line breaks specifically when running the format on a specific constructor. Since this is a function application (constructing the list), the point of view of the `scalafmt` is most likely that you either say that all function applications need to always have a line break in between arguments or none of them should.

Comment: Fair enough. It would be nice to have some config option to keep the newlines in all places (at least). I thought `newlines.source = keep` may help but...

Comment: Looking at the FAQs it looks like this is almost an anti-goal for `scalafmt`. You might want to have a look at `scalariform` perhaps. https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/faq.html#why-not-scalariform

Comment: Although `scalariform` looks abandoned...